# BizTalk Memory Usage per item

Tags: memory, biztalk

I recently began outbalancing our host instance memory usage because we had a lot of throttling problems.

Now I used performance counters to view the memory usage of each host instance.
And I also used a tool called the MsgBoxViewer to get to see which ports/locations/orchestrations run per host instance.

Now I was wondering if there is a way to see how much memory each of these subitems use? So I can outbalance it even more.

If no, is there a way to see how much traffic each host processes? I could then just use simple math to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can see the numbers at 'service' level, I would think that host instance level is the lowest level, but you could quite easily create the one host instance you'd use for your monitoring, and move one thing at a time there. 
So- for example - move one of the send ports to this host (which should have a single instance) and run your test suite, monitoring it's memory consumption.

The  move the send port back to it's original host and move something else into the test host and so on.

Granted - it's a bit more work than you would have hoped, I'm sure, but does the trick and not difficult.